# Ajax delete method giving error - Fuseki server

Tags: ajax, sparql, fuseki

I am having trouble with update and delete through ajax. I am getting an error in SPARQL Query but the query should be fine. Here is my code:

```
function deletePerson(per){
myQuery= ["DELETE{",
"<"+per+"> ?p ?o.",
"?s1 ?p1 <"+per+">.",
"}WHERE{",
"<"+per+"> ?p ?o.",
"OPTIONAL{",
"?s1 ?p1 <"+per+">.}}"].join(" ");
window.alert(myQuery);
$.ajax({
dataType: 'text',
type: 'POST',
url: "http://localhost:3030/Test/update",
data: {'query': myQuery, 'update': 'delete', '_method': 'delete'},
success: function(data) {
        window.alert('Deleted');
    },
error: myError
});
console.log('After .ajax');
```

}

The error I am getting is Sparql Error 400: Encountered "EOF" at line 1, column 6.?Was expecting:?    "{" ...?

Comment: did you read my comment in your last question? The param name has to be `update` and not `query`

Comment: Queries using the `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and various other SPARQL verbs that "write" — basically, any query discussed in [SPARQL 1.1 Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) — are all considered `UPDATE` queries and must be passed to Fuseki with the `update` param. Confusion is understandable since, though the *SPARQL 1.1 Update* Language is distinct from the *SPARQL 1.1 Query Language*, the grammar of both is included in the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) document.